# How to export a file to the same folder the .nb file is in, wherever it is?

Tags: export

For organizational purposes I would like to export my files to the same folder my notebook is in, but I want to be able to move the folder with .nb file around without having to rewrite the export command again and again. Is this possible?

Right now I'm doing something like this

```
Export["C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\GH Shift\\Angular Distribution\\DATA.dat", DATA, "TSV"]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `NotebookDirectory[]`? p.s. I think that the linked topic is a good enough duplicate, let me know if you disagree.